# Problem with Tensorflow object detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to setup Tensorflow for my computer with this turorial: https://medium.com/@teyou21/setup-tensorflow-for-object-detection-on-ubuntu-16-04-e2485b52e32a

After this step:

```
“export PYTHONPATH=:/home/bisaiya/Dev/VSCode_Workspace/mla/ObjectDetection/models/research:/home/bisaiya/Dev/VSCode_Workspace/mla/ObjectDetection/models/research/slim:/home/bisaiya/Dev/VSCode_Workspace/mla/ObjectDetection/models/research
```

And this:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install (I got error in this)

    running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/test-easy-install-8893.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

Thanks!

Comment: you tried using sudo command?

Comment: After I used sudo, the process after won't run right
` python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py`